# I need to pass a variable into a method

Tags: java, methods, static

In my code I created a class called Points which checks answer for given question and returns score. Another class called Report takes some information to prints it

```
package finalproject;

public class Points {

public static float calculatePoints(byte[] userAnswer) {

    byte realAnswer[], gradeCounter;
    float score ;
    gradeCounter = 0;

    realAnswer = new byte[3];
    realAnswer[0] = 3;
    realAnswer[1] = realAnswer[2] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < userAnswer.length; i++) {
        if (userAnswer[i] == realAnswer[i]) {
            gradeCounter++;
        }
    }

    score = (gradeCounter / 3) * 100;

    return score;
}



}

package finalproject;

public class Report {

public static void getLoginInfo(String[] loginInformation) {

    loginInformation = new String[2];
    String name, id;
    name = loginInformation[0];
    id = loginInformation[1];

}

public static void printReport() {

    System.out.println("\n\n-------------------\n\n");
    System.out.println("\t\tJava Certification");
    System.out.println("\t\t Test Result\n\n");
    System.out.println("\tName: ");
    System.out.println("\tTest Registration ID: ");
    System.out.println("\tPassing Score 52%");
    System.out.println("\tYour Score: ");

    /*
     * if (score1 >= 52.0) { System.out.println("\n\nComment GRADE: pass\n\n"); }
     * else { System.out.println("\n\nComment GRADE: fail\n\n"); }
     */

    System.out.println("Max Score\t" + "---------------100%");
    System.out.println("Max Score\t" + "--------52%");

}

}
```

In getLoginInfo variable called name and id should be set and I want to pass them into printReport.

I want to pass variable called score in function calculatePoint() to printReport how can I do it ?

Comment: by passing it as a parameter

Comment: if I passing it as a parameter I will call report class in the main then I can't pass any thing !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a bit confusing, because it seems like you know how to pass variables - you're already doing it with the `byte[]` in `calculatePoints()`. Why can't you pass your other values in the same way?

Comment: I know that put if I give it a parameter and then I called it in main then it would to take a parameter again

Comment: I think you probably need to revisit which code you've included in the question - it doesn't seem like what you've shown here expresses the problem you're encountering. I'm guessing you have a scenario where you want to be able to print some output by calling `printReport` from your `main` method, without any parameters, but also for `printReport` to include some values that are passed in from elsewhere. Maybe include the relevant part of your `main` method? Have a look at [How to create a MCVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare name and id outside any function the scope of strings name and id would be that of class meaning it will be visible to all functions in class Report. Each object/instance of class report will have name and id as attributes. Then getLoginInfo can be used to set and printReport() can be used to print name and id.

```
public class Report {
String name, id;
public static void getLoginInfo(String[] loginInformation){
    name = loginInformation[0];
    id = loginInformation[1];

}

public static void printReport() {

  ...
}
}
```

Comment: if I do that and called printReport in main then I should give it a parameter again !

Comment: @Adham I am sorry but I am not getting you. I though you wanted printReport to print different things so I modified the function. But the the title of question is "i need to pass variable into method" and you say you want to pass parameter from main. Could you clarify what exactly do you want?

Comment: Do you want print report to print data obtained from getLoginInfo()?

Comment: printReport should print some data like name and ID and Score

Comment: @Adham Yes but printReport should be able to receive data in some way. It could be hardcoded like print("Hello") or you could create object of class Report as explained in my modified answer and attribute of object can be printed or you can pass argument to the function. There should be be a way to tell the function which data to print. How would you like to pass data to function if you dont want arguments?

Comment: I have 4 classes in Java

Main
ProgramInterFace
Points
Report

In Tany Claas, I am presented with a question and the user responds to it by two periods, calling a class named points to calculate the percentage of answers

Two dimensions imposed in the other in the class named Report
Type the user name, id, and percentage that I calculated in Points
How to enter the class named

Comment: @Adham, sorry dude, but your attempts to explain this are just making it more confusing! Please take a step back, think about the specific question you want to be answered, and edit your post to include the absolute minimum amount of code that shows the problem. Forget about trying to explain it in comments, that's not going to help when the main question isn't being understood.